# What are the best ways to integrate images in latex/overleaf?

Tags: article, overleaf

[image]

Hi, I want to combine multiple sub figures that are in pdf files (i.e.  a, b-j) into one figure without losing resolution (dpi). I am using latex, it will be great if anyone can guide me on this.

Thanks

Comment: Assuming your pdf contains actual vector graphics, you can simply import them with `\includegraphics` in latex. They will be included as vector graphics, so no quality loose at all.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz yes, i have separate pdf files for all from a to j and i want latex syntax to merge them as in above, with (a), (b), (c) ... label and one caption for whole merged figure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `subcaption` package to align your images in such a pattern:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]

\begin{minipage}[c]{.45\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
  \subcaption{}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill%
\begin{minipage}[c]{.45\linewidth}%

  \begin{minipage}[b]{.33\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
    \subcaption{}
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{.33\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
    \subcaption{}
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{.33\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
    \subcaption{}
  \end{minipage}%  

  \begin{minipage}[b]{.33\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
    \subcaption{}
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{.33\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
    \subcaption{}
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{.33\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
    \subcaption{}
  \end{minipage}%  
  
  \begin{minipage}[b]{.33\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
    \subcaption{}
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{.33\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
    \subcaption{}
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{.33\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
    \subcaption{}
  \end{minipage}%

\end{minipage}%

\caption{Some caption}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]